# data.table 1.8.11 and aggregation issues

Tags: r, data.table

### **UPDATE**: BUG FIXED.  See below.

---

Here's some interesting behavior I found with data.table 1.8.11 (r1101, 2014-01-28). The order of the variables included in the by clause changes the results of an aggregation:

```
>   foo = data.table(a=rep(c(0,1,0,1),2), b=rep(c(T,T,F,F),2), c=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
>   foo
   a     b c
1: 0  TRUE 1
2: 1  TRUE 1
3: 0 FALSE 1
4: 1 FALSE 1
5: 0  TRUE 1
6: 1  TRUE 1
7: 0 FALSE 1
8: 1 FALSE 1
>   foo[, .N, by=list(b, a)]
       b a N
1:  TRUE 0 1
2:  TRUE 1 1
3: FALSE 0 1
4: FALSE 1 1
5:  TRUE 0 1
6:  TRUE 1 1
7: FALSE 0 1
8: FALSE 1 1
>   foo[, .N, by=list(a, b)]
   a     b N
1: 0  TRUE 2
2: 1  TRUE 2
3: 0 FALSE 2
4: 1 FALSE 2
>
```

This does not happen in the stable release of data.table (1.8.10).

Comment: No, not for me it doesn't. **data.table_1.8.11** on Windows 7. I get as expected, the second result. Do you really see this in a fresh session, copy/pasting from the question? Using **R_3.0.2** btw.

Comment: must be a newly introduced issue - I don't see it in a couple of months old revision

Comment: I can confirm the same results.  [It has been submitted as a bug](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5307). Thanks for the catch

Comment: Ok, I'm using **revision 1001** dated **2013-10-16** which works as expected. Gosh, I'm 100 revisions behind....

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Thanks for submitting the issue. I also added version information to the post.

Comment: Clayton, thanks, will look into this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Thanks for reporting. This is now fixed in v1.8.11 commit 1103. From [**NEWS**](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?root=datatable&r1=1103&view=log):

> o  Fixed a bug that arose due to recent fixes to fastorder, where aggregating with logical type at times lead to to wrong result. This closes #5307. Thanks to Clayton Stanley for reporting on SO: [data.table 1.8.11 and aggregation issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437546/data-table-1-8-11-and-aggregation-issues)

---

```
require(data.table) # commit 1103 v1.8.11
foo[, .N, by=list(b,a)]
       b a N
1:  TRUE 0 2
2:  TRUE 1 2
3: FALSE 0 2
4: FALSE 1 2

foo[, .N, by=list(a,b)]
   a     b N
1: 0  TRUE 2
2: 1  TRUE 2
3: 0 FALSE 2
4: 1 FALSE 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt fix. Verified that the change works for my actual use case as well.